# How to handle 401 error in angularjs select2?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I did use an http interceptor to handle 401 response status like following

```
var expiredSessionInterceptor = function ($q,$window)  {  
return {  
    request: function (config)  {   
        return config; 
    },  
    requestError: function (rejection)  {  
        // Contains the data about the error on the request and return the promise rejection.    
        return $q.reject(rejection);  
    },  
    response: function (response)  {
        return response;  
    },  
    responseError: function (response)  { 
        if (response.status == 401) {
            $window.location.href = '/Cortex_IP/j_spring_security_logout.do'; 
        }  
        return $q.reject(response);  
    }  
};
```

};

and it works every other ajax call expect select2 and its not intercepted by the above one .,
The select2 box continue loading (busy) when 401 error occurs.
Any one help me to handle 401 error in select2 in angularjs